# Convergence of maximum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(X_n)_n$ are i.i.d with density $f(x)=\delta x^{-(\delta+1)}$ for $x>1$ and $\delta>1$ is fixed. I am trying to show that

$$ \lim_n \frac{E(\max_{1\le i\le n}|X_i|)}{n^\varepsilon}=\infty$$

whenever $\varepsilon<1/\delta$. I have shown that if $\varepsilon=1$ The above goes to 0, by basic DCT/union bound. Trying to introduce the density I get that

$$ n^{-\varepsilon}{E(\max|X_i|)}= \int_1^\infty n^{-\varepsilon}P(\max_i |X_i|>x)\,dx =\int_1^\infty n^{-\varepsilon}(1-(1-x^{-\delta})^n)\,dx.$$

Unfortunately, all the convergence theorems we know are.... well for convergence. We cant use anything to show it diverges to infinity. Even showing that the integrand converges to 0 isn't enough as the integral can still diverge.

Comment: What about that limit are you trying to show?

Comment: Notice that $1\leq X_i \leq X_i^r$ for all $r\geq 1$.  And it holds for certain $r\geq 1$ that $E[X_i^r]$ is still finite, which is helpful to identify when that limit is 0.

Comment: FIXED, I want it to go to infinity. showing something goes to 0 or converging to something finite I am more comfortable with as we have many theorems to use to help us

Comment: You can integrate that nonnegative function over a subinterval of $x$ near $x=n^{1/\delta}$ so the integrand is approximately $n^{-\epsilon}(1-e^{-1})$ multiplied by the length of the subinterval.

Comment: The issue is that subinterval can be very small in length.  So the integral can be small locally

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?